# systemd user script fails on CentOS7 with: "Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory"

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7, systemd

## Problem

I'm trying to create a CentOS7 systemd user script - to keep-alive several VirtualBox VMs.

However, when I try to manually test it, I get[1]:

```
$  systemctl --user start virtualbox.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

## Details

```
$ cat /home/qa/.local/share/systemd/user/virtualbox.service
[Unit]
Description=Keep VirtualBox VMs up-and-running

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/qa/start_vms.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
$ cat /home/qa/start_vms.sh
/usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm QAT-116-sonarsql-test-virtualbox  --type headless
/usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm QAT-116-oracle12  --type headless
/usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm QAT-116-finder-tests_oori  --type headless
$ ls -ls /home/qa/.local/share/systemd/user/virtualbox.service /home/qa/start_vms.sh
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 qa qa 163 Jun 13 16:58 /home/qa/.local/share/systemd/user/virtualbox.service
4 -rwxrw-r-- 1 qa qa 211 Jun 13 16:49 /home/qa/start_vms.sh
$ whoami
qa
```

*Any suggestions on how to make the systemd script work on CentOS?*

## Edit 1

```
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1000
$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
$ ls /run/user/1000/bus
ls: cannot access /run/user/1000/bus: No such file or directory
$ systemctl status dbus.service
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-06-13 17:32:32 PDT; 17h ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 3797 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─3797 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation

...
$ systemctl --user status
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

---

[1] Googling this error message didn't give any worthwhile results.